# How to Clear BindingSource?

Tags: c#

I have a DevExpress GridControl with BindingSouce. I want to clear a BindingSource and fill it with new data. I do:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
bindingSource.DataSource = list;

//**Do somthing with a data**//

bindingSource.DataSource = listOfMyClassObjects;
```

And after it i see a big red cross instead my GridControl.
How to clear BindingSource correctly?

Comment: How do you set datasource to grid control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to clear the `BindingSource` of `GridControl`, you can assign `null` to it's `DataSource` before you fill with new data.

```
bindingSource.DataSource = null;
bindingSource.DataSource = listOfMyClassObjects;
```

You might also refer to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547439/correct-way-to-unbind-a-bindingsource-from-a-datagridview).