# C# Bound value does not match database

Tags: c#, sql-server

C# VS2010 Forms Application

I have a C# project with a SQL Server database (`.mdf` file) which includes an ID field, data type int, nulls not allowed; so that it autonumbers.

In my main form I bound the table to a bindingsource and the ID field is bound to a label.

All form controls and binding properties for them were made, without code, in the properties window.

The form includes a bindingnavigator, which has a + button (add record).
The instant that the + button is clicked, a value of -1 is assigned to the ID field; presumably as a temporary value, but this occurs automatically without any code behind.

Then when I INSERT INTO all of the values in the bound controls into their respective columns  of the database (this code is working properly), except ID which is automatically assigned by the database (auto incrementing int).
So this is why the value in the bound control does not match the one stored in the database.

This is preventing me from continuing with creating a method to delete a record by referencing the ID field, because the value (-1) in the bound control is invalid, i.e. no such record exists in the database.

I have tried `BindingSource.ResetBindings` method and refreshing the label, but the value remains -1 until exiting and restarting the program.

I also found suggestions to try setting `BindingSource.DataSource` to null then rebinding, but trying to set either the datasource or datamember to null throws an exception. I found another that suggested setting `BindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents` to false, but the exception still occurred.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Address_Book
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {

        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //***Program Execution***
            fillContactGrid();
        }    
        private void fillContactGrid()
        //This method retrieves and displays all records from ContactInfo
        {         
            //Create a connection to the database
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ContactsConnectionString))
            {               
                //Construct the SQL Query string
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ContactInfo";
                //Open the connection
                connection.Open();
                //Pass the query to the database and receive dataset
                SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();               
                dataadapter.Fill(ds, "ContactInfo");
                //Close the connection
                connection.Close();
                //Load the dataset into GridView
                contactsGridView.DataSource = ds;
                contactsGridView.DataMember = "ContactInfo";
            }
        }

        private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Initialize contactsDataSet
            this.contactInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.contactsDataSet.ContactInfo);
        }

        private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            disableNavigation();
            //Show save and cancel buttons
            buttonSave.Visible = true;
            buttonCancel.Visible = true;
        }

        private void disableNavigation()
        {
            //Temporarily disable navigator controls
            bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Enabled = false;
            bindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Enabled = false;
            bindingNavigatorPositionItem.Enabled = false;
            bindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem.Enabled = false;
            bindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.Enabled = false;
            bindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Enabled = false;
            bindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Cancel new record entry
            contactInfoBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
            //Hide save and cancel buttons
            buttonSave.Visible = false;
            buttonCancel.Visible = false;
            enableNavigation();
        }

        private void enableNavigation()
        {
            //Enable navigator controls
            bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Enabled = true;
            bindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Enabled = true;
            bindingNavigatorPositionItem.Enabled = true;
            bindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem.Enabled = true;
            bindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.Enabled = true;
            bindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Enabled = true;
            bindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            insertNewContact(); 
        }

        private void insertNewContact()
        {       
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ContactsConnectionString))
            {
                //***Construct the SQL Command string
                //Format: INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...)
                //Command
                string sqlCmd = "INSERT INTO ";
                //Table name
                sqlCmd += @"ContactInfo ";
                //Column names
                sqlCmd += @"(LastName, ";
                sqlCmd += @"FirstName, ";
                sqlCmd += @"Relationship, ";
                sqlCmd += @"Title, ";
                sqlCmd += @"Company, ";
                sqlCmd += @"OfficePhone, ";
                sqlCmd += @"OfficeExtension, ";
                sqlCmd += @"CellPhone, ";
                sqlCmd += @"HomePhone, ";
                sqlCmd += @"Email1, ";
                sqlCmd += @"Email2) ";
                //Values
                sqlCmd += @"VALUES ";
                sqlCmd += @"(@LastName, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@FirstName, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@Relationship, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@Title, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@Company, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@OfficePhone, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@OfficeExtension, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@CellPhone, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@HomePhone, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@Email1, ";
                sqlCmd += @"@Email2)";
                //Open the connection
                connection.Open();
                //Pass the command to the database
                using (SqlCommand command =new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textLastName.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textFirstName.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Relationship", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textRelationship.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textTitle.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Company", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textCompany.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@OfficePhone", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textOfficePhone.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@OfficeExtension", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textOfficeExtension.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@CellPhone", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textCellPhone.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@HomePhone", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textHomePhone.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Email1", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textEmail1.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Email2", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textEmail2.Text;
                    try
                    {
                        int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
                buttonSave.Visible = false;
                buttonCancel.Visible = false;                
                enableNavigation();
            }
        }

        private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
        {
            //Update the binding grid when its tab is selected
            fillContactGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's causing the exception?

Comment: contactInfoBindingSource.DataSource = null; Cannot bind to the property or column ID on the DataSource.

Comment: Edit the question and insert that code, insert the surrounding code as well so other users can get an idea of what you're doing - take the amount of code posted here as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753030/collect-moves-of-two-twodimensional-arrays-2048

Comment: The code that I have is not the problem, the problem is that the value in the label bound to the ID column does not match the actual value stored in the ID column of the database.  I need code to correct this, but none of the suggestions I have found in similar posts work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449461/how-to-clear-bindingsource checked answer indicates setting DataSource to null, but as stated above, this throws and acception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547439/correct-way-to-unbind-a-bindingsource-from-a-datagridview also indicates setting the DataSource to null is the best way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941537/better-way-to-update-bound-controls-when-changing-the-datasource Answer checked didn't work and comments indicate that setting DataSouce to null didnt work.

Comment: @ashur668 - The reason he asks for code, is because from your explanation, we have no idea if it is a binding failure, a failure in your ORM, or in code you are using to read\write to the DB.  This is a very vague description for a problem that has an extreme number of variables in play.  You have numerous application levels here.  Post a code repro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while, but finally found the problem/solution.

On FormMain_Load Visual Studio added a line to fill the data adapter created when I bound controls to the BindingSource;

this.contactInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.contactsDataSet.ContactInfo);

Adding this line of code after completing the command.ExecuteNonQuery refreshed the data in the bound controls and the ID value of -1 was replaced by the correct value assigned by SQLServer.

Thank you very much to Brian. I learned a lot of new things from your assisting me that I am sure will be of benefit to me in the future.

Comment: Doing this effectively re-queries the entire dataset.  This isn't the best case, but I'm glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem as I can see it:

You are binding a dataset to controls in your application. You click the "+" button which generates a new row in your dataset and assigns the default `Id` of `-1`.  You then manually insert that data via `insertNewContact`, however you never actually retrieve the database issued `Id` and apply it to your dataset.  It doesn't matter how many times you reset your bindings if the value for the Id field is still `-1` in your dataset, nor do you refresh the dataset from the database.

You could do this in one of a number of ways.  You could simply call `fillContactGrid` after `insertNewContact`. Or you could `select @@identity` at the end of your query and update your dataset manually.  To do this you would need to change your database call to `command.ExecuteScalar()`.

Either way, somehow you need to retrieve that newly inserted Id from the database and update the appropriate row in our dataset.

If my memory serves me right(it's been a while). FYI, this is a bit hackish, but it demonstrates the concept:

Add: `sqlCmd += @"; select @@identity";`

Change:

```
int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to:

```
int newid = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
((DataSet)contactsGridView.DataSource).Tables["ContactInfo"].Select("Id = -1")[0].SetField("Id", newId);
```

Comment: fillContactGrid(); is in my code at the very bottom. The Grid does contain the proper value for ID when updated, but it is because it is filled by query rather than being bound.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect the bindings to do.  You must update the proper field in your dataset after doing the insert, if you do this, the binding will update.

Comment: For your second suggestions, I am not savy on how to implement. If you have time to provide more detail I would be glad, while trying to follow your suggestion on my own.  Thanks!

Comment: the bindings are simply between the ui controls and your dataset.  you have no binding between your dataset and the database, which doesn't really exist anyways.  So if you manually update your database(which is what you are doing), your dataset has no idea that the data has changed in the database.

Comment: Yeah, I got that...that was why I has expected BindingSource.ResetBinding method to work, but it didn't do anything. ResetBinding was called out as a solution for several similar previous questions and none of them indicated that method actually worked....unfortunately.

Comment: "your dataset has no idea that the data has changed in the database". I can safely assume that the database did change after I manually added a record.  Rather than a work around, I am hoping to understand how to command the BindingSource and bound controls to refresh similar to the way they do automatically when the form is loaded from scratch.

Comment: ResetBinding only resets the binding between the UI and the data, if the data is wrong, it will still show the incorrect data.

Comment: @ashur668- I added some code that should be pretty close.

Comment: There is no way to get your dataset to automatically update.  Something must trigger an update and cause your data to reload.  What you are looking for is something closer to an ORM such as Entity Framework (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).  There is no magic here.  Databases generally do not notify clients of table changes(there are exceptions), your code is responsible for re-querying the database and updating your UI.

Comment: The SQL command addition seems ok, but Int32 newID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();  ((DataSet contactsGridView.DataSource).Tables["ContactInfo"].Rows.Find(-1)["Id"] = newID; returns Specified cast not valid.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I updated my answer.  You need to use the SetField method on the row.

Comment: Unless the error is coming from the ExecuteScalar, in which case my guess is that your Id field is not really a primary key IDENTITY field, which might make @@Identity return null.  Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Still indicating cast invalid.

Comment: Try changing int newid = (int)command.ExecuteScalar(); to object newid = command.ExecuteScalar(); and check what value you get back for newid in the debugger.  If newid is null, your Id field is likely not an actual identity field in SQL.

Comment: I tried using the SQL shown in this example and it returned "Table doesn't have a primary key"., but I checked and it does...new mystery: why does it not recognize primary key. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: not a mystery.  just because the table has a primary key doesn't mean that your dataset knows about it.  We need to tell the dataset that it has a primary key, or find the row without a primary key.  I will edit my answer shortly to accommodate this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx

Comment: When you fill a dataset from an adapter using hand-crafted SQL, the only information the adapter knows about is what is returned in the query, which does not include enough schema information to understand primary keys.

Comment: Frankly, this whole exercise is one of the reasons that I avoid datasets like the plague

Comment: The field in the table needs to be the primary key and marked as an identity field

Comment: The ID column in the database is (always has) been marked as primary key with (Is Identity) set to Yes....mystery continues?

Comment: Ok...I think I found part of the problem.  Your focused in on the GridView which is not bound to the database.  The ID label is bound via contactInfoBindingSource.  So I altered the line to read ((DataSet)contactInfoBindingSource.DataSource).Tables["ContactInfo"].Rows.Find(-1).SetField("ID", newID);...now it this line returns Value cannot be null. Parameter name: row...any idea?

Comment: Actually the exception identified with the catch statement.

Comment: The SQL did return the newID from the database, so I am assuming that Rows.Find(-1) returned nothing...?

Comment: Change it to Rows.Select("Id = -1")[0]

Comment: Select is not a valid extension of Rows.  Heading home now...thanks for all your help.  Hopefully I will be able to continue working on this tomorrow.